# Is this possible to implement this sql query to linq

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm having trouble in joining tables in linq because I'm checking if the `templateSetId` is existing in the template set table

Query:

```
select 
    vc.RowID, Choice_Text, VCE.[Goto] 
from 
    ropes.Validation_Choices vc
left outer join 
    ropes.Validation_Condition_Expression VCE 
      on VCE.ChoiceID = vc.RowID and TemplateSetID in 
                                     (select RowID 
                                      from ropes.Validation_Templates_Set 
                                      where TemplateID = 66)
where 
   vc.QuestionID = 81
```

This query returns 3 rows.

Moving the filter of templatesetid gives me an error "Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'bool'"
The best that i can to is this

```
from tc in _context.ValidationChoice
     join vce in _context.ValidationConditionExpression
     on tc.ChoiceId equals (int)vce.ChoiceID into lfc
     from lf in lfc.DefaultIfEmpty()
     where  tc.QuestionID == questionId &&
     (from ts in _context.ValidationTemplateSet where ts.TemplateID == templateId     select ts.TemplateSetId).Contains((int)lf.TemplateSetID)


                                 select new TemplateChoiceDTO
                                 {
                                     ChoiceId = tc.ChoiceId,
                                     ChoiceText = tc.ChoiceText,
                                     NextQuestionId = lf.Goto

                                 };
```

which is equivalent  to :

```
 select vc.RowID,Choice_Text,VCE.[Goto] from ropes.Validation_Choices vc
    left outer join ropes.Validation_Condition_Expression VCE on 
    VCE.ChoiceID = vc.RowID 
    where vc.QuestionID = 81 
    and TemplateSetID in (select RowID from ropes.Validation_Templates_Set where TemplateID = 66)
```

This query returns 1 row because the filter for templatesetid was move outside

Comment: What's the question? This looks like it should do the same. I think even the query plans will be identical for the two SQL queries.

Comment: Moving the filter of templatesetid gives me an error "Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'bool'"

Comment: @GertArnold The first query in sql returns 3 values while the second value returns  1 value, my question is if it is possible to convert `"select vc.RowID,Choice_Text,VCE.[Goto] from ropes.Validation_Choices vc
left outer join ropes.Validation_Condition_Expression VCE on 
VCE.ChoiceID = vc.RowID and TemplateSetID in (select RowID from ropes.Validation_Templates_Set where TemplateID = 66)
where vc.QuestionID = 81 "` to linq

Comment: Please add this to your question.